# How I can simulate with wiremock the remote service going down and up?

Tags: wiremock

I need to write an unit test to check the behavior of http connections in case the remote service is being restarted. Is it possible to simulate such a situation with wiremock ?

Comment: You can return a 503 service unavailable or something for any endpoint. Are you looking for something more complex?

Comment: @suite22 thanks for the comment but I'm rather looking for something like putting down wiremock and putting it up again.

Comment: if you're running WireMock outside JUnit you can call `wireMockServer.stop();` or the admin API has `/__admin/shutdown` but I'm not sure there's how you'd want to bring the server back up.